# What's wrong with my argument $f$ is Lipschitz?

Tags: analysis

Recall the definition:

$f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz if there is constant $L > 0$ such that $$|f(x)-f(y)| \le L|x-y|, \quad x,\,y \in [a,b]$$

I claim bounded functions are Lipschitz. Here's my argument.

We consider the case $x \ne y$.

If $f$ is bounded, then $|f(x)| \le M$ for some $M>0$. So $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f(x)|+|f(y)| \le 2M$. Let $L = 2M/|x-y|$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|$, Lipschitz condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $L$ must be a universal constant, that is, independent of $x$ and $y$.